# How could i fix the 'local variable 'prev_time' defined in enclosing scope on line 6 referenced before assignment" error

Tags: python, datetime, error-handling, shared-libraries

I am working with the "time" libray for python, Right now I am working on getting a date variable to update. Right now my code looks like this

```
def getTime():
  named_tuple = time.localtime()
  time_string = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y", named_tuple)
  prev_time = time_string

getTime()

if prev_time != time_string:
  getTime()
```

On the "prev_time != time string:" I keep getting the error "'local variable 'prev_time' defined in enclosing scope on line 6 referenced before assignment" I am relatively new to python so any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Global Scope.

```py
def getTime():
  global prev_time,time_string
  named_tuple = time.localtime()
  time_string = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y", named_tuple)
  prev_time = time_string

getTime()

if prev_time != time_string:
  getTime()
```